# Hide content_for for a particular page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I have `application.html.haml` file that has a navigation top bar. In a particular page, I would like not to use this bar.

How can I tell Rails not to inherit from application.html.haml file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `:layout => false` in the render for the particular controller action.

```
def page_with_no_layout

  .....

  render :layout => false 

end
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using

```
render :layout => false
```

You can also specify an alternate layout:

```
render :layout => 'no_top_bar_layout'
```

Or, you can add a conditional to your main layout that checks an instance variable, and skips the top bar part of the layout if that instance variable is set. It's a bit messier than the first two options, but might make sense in some limited situations.